# Can not use Show even if type implements it

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I do not understand why i `Show` typeclass complains on using a custom type since i already provided an instance for it :

**Custom Type**

```
data Numeric=I Int | D Double 

instance Show Numeric where
        show (I x)=show x
        show (D y)=show y

 instance Num Numeric where
        (+) (I a) (I b) =I (a+b)
        (+) (D a) (I b) =D (a+ fromIntegral b)
        (+) (I a) (D b)=D (fromIntegral a+b)
        (-) (D a) (I b)= D (a- fromIntegral b)
        (-) (I a) (D b)=D(fromIntegral a -b)
```

**Method that complains**

```
arrayToString::Num a=>[a]->String
arrayToString arr =intercalate "," $ map show arr
```

So given my `type` that implements `Num` and `Show` typeclasses  i do not understand why it has renders this error when i am feeding `arrayToString` a `[Numeric]` value

**Error**

```
* Could not deduce (Show a) arising from a use of `show'
      from the context: Num a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   arrayToString :: forall a. Num a => [a] -> String
        at Types.hs:40:5-37
      Possible fix:
        add (Show a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            arrayToString :: forall a. Num a => [a] -> Strin
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to show something then use the `Show` constraint:

```
arrayToString :: (Show a) => [a] -> String
```

> i do not understand why it has renders this error when i am feeding arrayToString a [Numeric] value

Notice the function `arrayToString` doesn't have anything specific to `Num` or `Numeric`.  All it does is render a string for anything Showable (via `show`).

Comment: So basically if my type `A` implements `T1` and `T2` typeclasses , and i only put a constraint for `T1` inside a method , it can't deduce that it implements `T2` too ?

Comment: Your function, `arrayToString` does not really have anything to do with your type `Numeric`, it's just a function that renders `Show`able values in a special way.  It can't render values that aren't Showable and `Num` has nothing to do with its operation.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you are *not* using your custom type.

The given type signature is `arrayToString :: forall a. Num a => [a] -> String`. You have universally quantified over all possible types `a` that are members of the `Num` typeclass. This *includes* your type but also every other numeric type that exists and ever will exist. This is too bold a statement.

You might want to consider changing the signature to `arrayToList :: [Numeric] -> String`, using your type directly, instead of relying on parametric polymorphism.

Also, as a side-note, `[]` is a singly linked list (or a cons-list), not an array.

EDIT: To translate this issue into logic, what you have done is to say

- There is a set of things called `Numeric`
- Elements of `Numeric` are members of the classes `Num` and `Show`
- Therefore, for *every possible type ever* that is in the `Num` class, I can turn a list of that type into a string

You have drastically increased the scope of the statement so that it includes a whole bunch of types we know nothing about and have no proof that they can be turned into strings.

Comment: If at the compile time, all known data types which are instances of `Num` type class are also an instance of `Show` type class like in the above case, wouldn't Haskell be able to deduce this information from `Num a => ` constraint alone..? What do you mean by *every possible type ever*..?

Comment: @Redu *"...all known data types which are instances of Num type class are also an instance of Show type class..."* This is not true in general, for example one could implement a `(Num b) => Num (a -> b)` instance. Haskell refuses to deduce that all `Num`s are `Show`s, because that may not be true later on.

Comment: @AJFarmar Thanks for the comment. I understand and normally i wouldn't bother much and listen to the error message, just throw a `Show a` into the constaints mix. Seeing this question intrigued me a little. I would normally expect GHC to process instances in advance, rendering the possiblity of an unshowable `Num` type class type to pop up later. I think like, in the above example it gives the impression of unnecessarily whining while at the same time there must a certain reason while things done this way.

Comment: @Redu And if this is a library that may be imported by somebody else who has defined new instances GHC didn't know about at the time it created the library, what then?